# How to create an InputStream from a multiple array of strings

Tags: java, struct, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I have an 3 array of strings ( actually it's an ArrayList ) and I would like to create an InputStream from it, each element of the array being a line in the stream.

```
String[] business = ['CONSUMER', 'TELUS'];
String[] position = ['Business', 'SMB','THPS'];
String isDone = "Yes";
```

need to convert the above data into and pass it to InputStream so i can upload the data to ftp server

```
Business_Unit:     'TELUS', 'CONSUMER'
Position_Group:    'Business', 'SMB', 'THPS'
On-Cycle_Schedule: 'Yes'  or 'No
```

ftp server method as follows

```
    private boolean fileUpload(InputStream isUploadFile, String dirName, String fileName){
         boolean storeRetVal = false;

      //File submission method 

        
      return storeRetVal;
     }
```

the above method gets called from action class

```
public ActionForward generatePayroll(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                       HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   SessionInfoForm _form = (SessionInfoForm) form;
   String isDone = "Yes";
   String[] business = request.getParameterValues("selectedBusinessValues");
   String[] position = request.getParameterValues("selectedPositionValues");
   String fileName = "result.csv";
   InputStream isUploadFile;
   fileUpload(isUploadFile, fileName);
   return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

Comment: Difficult to advise as we don't know the real data. That code wouldn't compile so can't be the actual code

Comment: @g00se real data is String[] business = ['CONSUMER', 'TELUS'];
String[] position = ['Business', 'SMB','THPS'];
String isDone = "Yes";

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
   String[] business = { "CONSUMER", "TELUS" };
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sw);
    for (String s : business) {
        out.println(s);
    }
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sw.toString().getBytes());
```